# Linux, CPU-architecture in which file stored

Tags: linux, architecture, cpu

I like to know, in which file the value for the CPU architecture is stored on Linux e.g. `x86_64`.

I know several methods (shell commands) in order to access this value like `lscpu` or `uname -a`.

Furthermore I'm aware of the Qt-Method [`QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsysinfo.html). And they all provide the required information.

But I like to create an OS-Interface which retrieves the information of the underlying operating system (in my case Linux) only by using "Linux-Tools" like information from files in `/proc/...`.

I also know that I can run a shell command in my program by using `popen()` and access the results by the std streamer classes. That's no problem. But unfortunately we don't like run shell commands in our software.

I have looked in several files like
`/proc/version`, `/proc/cpuinfo`, `/proc/devices` or in files in subfolders of `/proc`.

But unfortunately it seems to me as if I always overlooked this piece of information. I'm sure that it has to be in a file because the method `QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture()` access this information, too.

So if somebody knows where this information is placed on Linux I would be happy if he or she let me know.

With kind regards

Answer (score 0):

According `man lscpu`

> `lscpu`  gathers  CPU  architecture information from sysfs,
> `/proc/cpuinfo` ...

looking for the information under `/proc` and `cpuinfo` was the right idea, since the information is there, but not in the format you were expecting. It is somehow "hidden" in line `flags`. You like to look for `lm` (long mode).

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "flags\| lm "
```

If the flag for long mode is set you are on `x86_64`.

Thanks / Credits to

- [What do the flags in /proc/cpuinfo mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/)
- [CPUID](https://www.sandpile.org/x86/cpuid.htm), bit 29 (LM)

How the information is gathered and processed you can find in [`sys-utils/lscpu.c`](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux/+/v2.23/sys-utils/lscpu.c), in example from line 369-378.

Other CPU modes are

- Real Mode, 16 bit CPU, Intel 8086 or 8080 emulation mode, all x86 CPU start in this mode after reset
- Protected Mode, 32-bit CPU